# How to implement windows authentication in spring based Java-application?

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc

How to implement windows authentication in spring based Java-application?
I have created authentication using spring security,But i want to use windows credential while user login to my application.

Comment: http://code.dblock.org/single-sign-on-spring-security-negotiate-filter-kerberos-ntlm-wwaffle

Answer (score 1):

It's not cross browser but you can try this https://github.com/michail-nikolaev/springsecurity3-activedirectory-ntlm-test

Comment: But client required windows authentication.